# A POST form that contains all properties of a model

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create a POST form that contains all properties in model. Each property would be set as hidden input item:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController"))
{           
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Field1)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Field2)
    ...
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FieldN)          

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Launch query</button>
}
```

Ideally, I would like to do something like (pseudocode):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController"))
{           
    foreach(var prop in m.Props)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[prop])
    }

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Launch query</button>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
@foreach (var property in Model.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    <input id="@property.Name" name="@property.Name" value="@property.GetValue(Model, null)" type="hidden" />
}
```

Comment: It works like a charm, thank you very much. I was overthinking it, trying to make it fit into ASP's `Html`. In my implementation of your code, I've added `var propValue = property.GetValue(Model, null); if(propValue != null) {  // write the <input> }`. This way I skip the empty properties, which are not necessary: they will be `null` in the model once the POST is sent anyway.